# selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated error Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, mousehover

I want to select the Code 128 (standard) from select menu, but whatever i did, i could not manage to select any option from the menu.

```
WebDriver   driver = Driver.get();
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(-1000, 0));
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.barcode-generator.org/");
BrowserUtils.waitFor(2);
driver.findElement(By.className("iubenda-cs-close-btn")).click();
BrowserUtils.waitFor(2);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='code_selector']"));
Select select = new Select(selectElement);
List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
BrowserUtils.waitFor(4);
System.out.println("options.size() = " + options.size());
select.selectByVisibleText("Code 128 (standard)");
driver.findElement(By.id("barcode_data")).sendKeys("abc");
```

And I got this response:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 53482
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Haz 18, 2023 1:53:26 ÖS org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
options.size() = 67

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.134)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
```

Comment: *Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated* Looks like the option is not there opr the  select field is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the `<option>` with text ***Code 128 (standard)*** is within the [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) tag but the `<select>` tag contains the attribute [`style="display: none;"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50852370/7429447):

```
<select style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); display: none;" id="code_selector">
```

Hence Selenium won't be able to interact with it.

---

### Solution

To click on the element with text with text ***Code 128 (standard)*** you need to [*Mouse Hover*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47261894/7429447) the parent element and then click on the `<button>` with text ***Create Barcode*** and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.barcode-generator.org/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.iubenda-cs-close-btn"))).click();
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("figure#code_figure_20")))).build().perform();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='create-overlay']//div[@class='inner-cell']//button[@data-choose='20' and contains(., 'Create Barcode')]"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Code 128 (standard)]